# use google-app-engine firewall to receive email relay from specific IP

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, firewall

we have a GAE email receiver, which is able to receive email from specific IP, now our we want to emails from this IP only , and reject others ip.
we use GAE-firewall to set deny all but only allow this ip, but it does not work. I set deny all ip as default(the default rule),then set allow rule for specific IP with priority, I could use browser to access this app-engine instance, but firewall rejects all coming emails, include the my laptop which I can access this app-engine instance by browser,  how should I config that to achieve receive email from specific IP only?
the seting is:
priority for specific ip is "1",
priority for deny all is "default",sorry for the image not shown
[image: how we set firewall]

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Are requests still received from any IP? Or all requests are now denied regardless of the source IP?

Comment: Did you set the priority order?  Did you test using "Test IP address"?

Comment: @GAEfan
I set the priority, the deny * is as default,  allowed ip is has number priority

Comment: @LundinCast
it deny all email coming once I set the deny rule, but I can use browser to access with the pc ip i set to allow access firewall

Comment: Can you confirm once what priority have you set on the IP address that you want to allow?

Comment: @Mousumi Roy priority for specific ip is "1", priority for deny all is "default"

Comment: Can you confirm which connections are you using IPv4 or IPv6? If not IPv6, can you check with it once?